# Mongodb spring data object store into mysql

Tags: java, mysql, mongodb

I have an application that uses both mongodb and mysql.We are using mongodb to provide scalabality and mysql for provding relational mapping. Now I have one common table called Audit available in both databases. I want to copy that table data from mongodb to mysql. my class is for mongodb

```
@document(collection="AUDIT_LOG")
Class AuditLog{
    @Id
    String id;
    String currentNodeId;
    String currentNodeType;
    Date timStamp;
}
```

My Hibernate class is:

```
Class AuditLog{
    Long objId;
    Long objVersion;
    String currentNodeId;
    String currentNodeType;
    Date timStamp;
}
```

Now on specified time interval I want to copy the mongodb Audit collection data into the mysql. Is there any short way to do. I am using spring data for storing domain object into the mongodb. and using hibernate to store object in mysql